# I think I opened an unsafe unix exe file! Can anyone tell me what this file might've done?

Tags: dmg, virus

I was downloading a crack file for premier 2019 pro cc as something went wrong with my subscription and now I don't have premier, so when I opened the dmg. It showed an installer and I went through with the installation...(stupidly) nothing changed, but I am scared that I might have caused an issue to my computer.

How can I make sure that my system didn’t get infected by malware?

PS: I still have the .dmg on my computer in case I need it to see if damage can be reversed.

I don't know how to read the script or anything and I am just worried I might have given someone access to my personal and private information or might have caused an issue for may computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Nobody can tell you what happened to your computer.  I would recommend that you at least disable any backups and download Malwarebytes.  Run several scans on your system.  You might need to erase your drive and reinstall your OS and programs.

Comment: Malware is always a risk you run when you download things claiming to be illegal cracks from dubious sources. If you need a decent Photo editing app and don't want to pay Adobe's subscription rates, just buy Affinity Photo from the Mac App Store.

Comment: Why not just download GIMP-it's free and is pretty good (a past user, no affiliation)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about how to supply a software crack, and has no actionable information in it.

Comment: *I was downloading a crack file....*  If you make that statement, assume you downloaded malware.  Wipe your drive and restore from backup.

Answer (score 1):

Without analyzing the scripts etc you run nobody can tell what (if anything) happened to your computer. To recover the best course of action is to restore from a backup made *before* you opened the DMG.